# Output on new line WITHOUT for loop

Tags: java

I am trying to output arrays on a new line through a basic client, server application. However, to accomplish this I have had to use substring to find the # after each word to signal the end of the line. However I want to remove this function and have each section on a new line.

```
    public ClientHandler(Socket socket,Users newUser, int newClientUser)
                                                    throws IOException
{
    client = socket;
    input = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
    output = new PrintWriter(
                    client.getOutputStream(),true);
    user = newUser;
    clientUser = newClientUser;

    String[] itemName = {user.getItemName(1), user.getItemName(2)};
    String[] description = {user.getItemDescription(1), user.getItemDescription(2)};
    String[] itemtime = {user.getItemTime(1), user.getItemTime(2)};

    output.println(itemName[0] + "@" + itemName[1] 
        + "@" + "Welcome To The Auction User:" + clientUser
         + itemName[0] +": "+ description[0] +
        "@"+ itemName[1] +": "+description[1]+
        "@"+ "Deadline For " + itemName[0] + ": " 
        + itemtime[0] + "#" +"Deadline For " + 
        itemName[1] + ": " + itemtime[1]+"@");

}

private synchronized void getMessage(String response) 
{
    String message="";
    for(int i= count; !response.substring(i, i+1).equals("@"); i++)
    {
       count = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output.println(itemName[0] + "\n" + itemName[1] 
        + "\n" + "Welcome To The Auction User:" + clientUser
         + itemName[0] +": "+ description[0] +
        "\n"+ itemName[1] +": "+description[1]+
        "\n"+ "Deadline For " + itemName[0] + ": " 
        + itemtime[0] + "\n" +"Deadline For " + 
        itemName[1] + ": " + itemtime[1]+"\n");
```

Instead of having a "#" signify a new line, you can use "\n". Java will read that from your string as a new line.

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand your question, so I tried answering it as best as I could.